# Angularjs $filter usage inside a custom filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have a custom filter with a $filter dependency:

```
app.filter('getRange',[ '$filter', function($filter) {
    return function(data, data2) {
        console.log(data); //this is empty
        var result = $filter('3dparty_filter')(data,data2);
        var another_var = $filter('another_filter')(result);
        //do smth.
    }
}]);
```

For some reason the arguments(data, data2) of the filter are empty. However, if I remove the `$filter` dependency

```
app.filter('getRange',function() {
    return function(data, data2) {
         console.log(data); //this works, data is not empty.
       // var result = $filter('3dparty_filter')(data,data2);
       // var another_var = $filter('another_filter')(result);
       //do smth.

    }
});
```

everything works fine (i.e. data and data2 args are passed correctly). 
Could you please advise on how to properly inject $filter in my case or why the args are empty and how to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

Please see example here http://jsbin.com/ticoho/1/edit?html,js,console,output evrything is fine. Double check your html or there is a problem with 3rd part filters

```
app.filter('getRange',['$filter',  function($filter) {
    return function(data, data2) {
      console.log(data);
      console.log(data2);
        return $filter('json')(data);

    };
}]);
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I did not clarified it. I need to use $filter inside my custom filter. Unfortunately, your code is wrong as $filter is not injected therefore ReferenceError arises.

Comment: "Could you please advise on how to properly use $filter in my case?"